# How to generate JSON format with title

Tags: php, json, parsing

```
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM recipe");


$encode = array();

while($allRow = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {
        $new = array(
                    'id' => $allRow['id']);


        $encode[] = $new;

    }
echo  json_encode($encode);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I have a bad format of my Json..

```
[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"3"},{"id":"4"},{"id":"5"},{"id":"6"},{"id":"7"}]
```

i need to have something like this
[enter link description here](http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/)

Comment: you are only adding id to the array, so of course you dont see the other data

Answer (score 2):

Well for each of your recipes you would add the attributes that you want to appear.

```
    $new = array(
                'id' => $allRow['id'],
                'title'=>$allRow['title'],
                'ingredients'=>$allRows['ingredients']);
    $encode[] = $new;
```

etc.

Then you would create a wrapper arround the encode object at the time you call the json_encode

```
 $json = json_encode(array("recipes"=>$encode));
```